How to access to values set in an initializer in `Rails.application.configure`?
I have a global constant (APP_CONFIG) for all my custom configs that reads settings from app_config.yml file.
I initialize this constant in config/initializer/00_load_app_config.rb file.
I want to access to these configs values on my Rails.application.configure like:
config.action_mailer.asset_host = APP_CONFIG[:host]

But when Rails.application.configure executes, my initializer still has not been executed.
I tried:
config.action_mailer.asset_host = -> { APP_CONFIG[:host] }

In case I could make use of some lazy magic, but it didn't work.

Short answer -- you can't -- the initializers are run later in the start process. https://guides.rubyonrails.org/initialization.html -- you will note that the config/initializers are discussed as a follow on topic https://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#using-initializer-files

@dbugger check my answer, let me know what do you think

I used config.after_initialize to  solve it:
# config/environments/development.rb
Rails.application.configure do
  [...normal configs here]
end

# at the end
Rails.application.config.after_initialize do
  Rails.configuration.action_mailer.asset_host = APP_CONFIG[:host]
end

It is not the most elegant way because it forces me to separate part of the configuration to the end of the file, and it may be the case I forgot this is there when I look for it in the future (or another developer is looking for it).

if it solves your need  - excellent
